# What preparatory steps should I be taking for admission into med school?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I've been maintaining a great GPA in a specialization undergraduate program, am planning on taking the MCAT this summer, and have been looking into some volunteering/internship opportunities. Are there any other special precautions that I should be taking to increase the likelihood of my acceptance into med school? Are med schools looking for anything in particular for admissions? An all-encompassing, comprehensive answer would be appreciated, but any advice or tips are appreciated :).

Comment: I'm currently studying in Canada, and plan to keep doing so, if that matters.

Comment: Why the downvote? How can this question be improved?

Comment: Upvoted.  This is a straightforward question about admission to a post-graduate academic program; I think it's perfectly in scope.  Whether we lack the expertise to give a useful answer is a separate issue.

Comment: @bobthejoe: yes, none relevant to medicine, but why do you "HATE" medical students? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking from (1) experience applying and talking to applications officers, and (2) knowing doctors who take part in the admissions process, I would suggest that the ideal medical student would appear as follows:

- Any major, but very high grades in all pre-med courses
- Very high MCAT score
- Experience working in a hospital *or* medical research lab, with demonstrated results (good recommendations from doctors and published papers, respectively)
- Very personable during the interview, well-liked by all interviewers

None of these should be a surprise; they just want awesome, academic students.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to seek info from those that might know, such as:

- http://www.aspiringdocs.org/faqs/preparing/
- http://www.ama-assn.org/ama/pub/education-careers/becoming-physician/medical-school/preparing-medical-school.page
- https://www.aamc.org/students/considering/gettingin/

This site is aimed at questions about Academia, I can see how you might think this would be an appropriate place, but the sites listed above should directly answer your questions.

Have you spent time with some of your local medical professionals, found out about their jobs, their specialties?  Good luck!

Comment: Medical school is part of academia.  But it's a specific part, and your identifying sites where someone can get information specifically tailored to medical school admission is a good answer.